# Importing stock price from bloomberg to Google sheets

Tags: xml, google-sheets, stockquotes

I'm trying to import the stock price to my google sheets, unfortunately Google Financials dosen't support stocks from the Oslo Exchange at the moment. I have been browsing online, but none of the code examples works.

E.g.

```
=IMPORTXML(ʺhttps://www.bloomberg.com/quote/GJF:NOʺ,ʺ//span[@class='priceText__1853e8a5']ʺ)
```

Should supposedly

Anyone who has an suggestion on how I can make this work?

Comment: I still get errors when I'm changing the quotation marks. 
  
 =IMPORTXML("https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/GJF:NO","//span[@class='priceText__1853e8a5']")

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I am experiencing the same issue.

Answer (score 6):

`ImportHTML` works for me.
This returns the USD Spot Gold price

```
=Round(Index(ImportHTML("http://www.bloomberg.com/markets/commodities/futures/metals/","table",1),4,3),2)
```

and this GBP/EUR

```
=round(Index(ImportHTML("http://www.bloomberg.com/markets/currencies/cross-rates","table",1),3,5),5)
```

`ImportHTML` needs page source, table on page and row/col coordinates

Comment: If you're looking for the US silver spot, building on @Peter answer, this retrieves it:

=Round(Index(ImportHTML("http://www.bloomberg.com/markets/commodities/futures/metals/","table",2),4,3),2)

Answer (score 2):

This works for me. Example [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AF0Dull8YBgCCl1NsOS6QNbRNwnhkEum8F9ScEFuMYs/edit#gid=1168970219). Pretty sure your issue is quote types as mentioned above.

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/GJF:NO","//span[@class='priceText__1853e8a5']")
```

Comment: do you mean between the two variables in the IMPORTXML function? comma is what documentation shows and it still works as far as I can tell https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342?hl=en

Comment: Deleted my comment, my spreadsheet uses semicolon because the comma is set to be the decimal separator.